# Rails Conditional Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a project and need some help on where to begin. I have three pages

- Update User
- Create User
- Admin User Password Change (like a Hard Reset Password for but only the admin can reset the user's password)
- Change Password

On Create User first name, last name, username, password, and password confirmation are mandatory.

On Update User just first name, last name and username are mandatory.

On Admin User Password Change and Change Password, just password and password confirmation are mandatory.

How would you go about doing this? I don't think this is possible through models using validates_presence_of with an if because there are too many scenarios. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Also, I am pretty new to Rails if you can't already tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass conditionals to your validations:

```
validates :password, :confirmation => true, :presence => true
validates :first_name, :last_name, :username, :presence => true
validate :admin_user_password_change?
```

Of course you'd have to define what the `admin_user_password_change?` method would be to determine if it is an admin user changing a password.

**UPDATE**

The `admin_user_password_change?` method might be something like:

```
def admin_user_password_change?
  unless self.admin? && self.password.present? && self.password_confirmation.present?
    self.errors.add(:admin_password_change, "password and password_confirmation are required.")
  end
end
```

As for *How would it communicate with the controller?*, it wouldn't directly.  But if any of the conditions in the method are false (e.g. `self.admin? && self.password.present? && self.password_confirmation.present?`), an error will be added to the instance of `User` and the instance won't save in the controller.

Comment: How would the `admin_user_password_change` method in the Model communicate with the Controller? Basically, how do i define the `admin_user_password_change`?

Comment: @CDub this looks something suspicious, first thing user shouls set `validates :password, confirmation: true, presence: true` and then `validates :first_name, :last_name, :username` is sufficient for create and update. there is no need to set it again for update by excluding password field . model will not check that validation until user is try to set them nil

Comment: for checking that update is made by admin ,you have to create a virtual field for that in your model and then pass it with params to model when attempt to update . now in model you can check presence for that virtual field to validate password fields

Comment: @CDub sorry to interrupt you again but ` :on => [:create, :update]` not required at all . what other possibility left if you include both create and update. correct me if i am wrong  :)

Comment: you can not access `current_user` in model

Comment: @NitinJ - ha, no problem. updated again.  if anything looks wrong, feel free to edit :)

Comment: you can replace `validates :password, :password_confirmation, :presence => true, :if => :admin_user_password_change?` with `validate :admin_user_password_change?`

Comment: anyway +1 for all your effort

Answer (score 0):

Setting some fields to new values doesn't *unset* other fields; just because you're only updating *some* fields in one action doesn't mean the other fields will be *unset*, so long as they start in a consistent state.

Just add your validations. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell to your validation work only on certain cenarios only using:

The create:

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, :username, presence: true, on: :create
```

The update:

```
validates :password, presence: true, on: :update
```

Take a look at [on](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on).

For validation based on context take a look at [Context Validations](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2013/05/09/context-validations.html)